# Javascript trigger is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a search bar for desktop and for mobile

**This is the desktop**

```
<div class="wrap-search-header flex-w p-l-15  "  style="height: 50px;width: 650px;">                            
    <input class="plh3 search-input" type="text" name="search"   placeholder="Search...">
    <button class="flex-c-m trans-04 hov-btn1 search-btn">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-search"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

**This is mobile**

```
<div class="wrap-search-header flex-w p-l-15"  style="height: 50px;width: 350px;">
    <input class="plh3 search-input" type="text" name="search"   placeholder="Search...">
    <button class="flex-c-m trans-04 hov-btn1 search-btn">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-search"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

I want to create one function that triggers if either the mobile or desktop search button is clicked. so i tried this

```
$('.search-btn').on('click', function(){ 
    var searchinput = $('.search-input').value;
    console.log(searchinput)
})
```

but for some reason it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `var searchinput = $('.search-input').val();` instead of `var searchinput = $('.search-input').value;`.

You can also use `val()` to set values.

More info can be founded on the reference:
http://api.jquery.com/val/

Also don't forget to wrap the code inside `$(document).ready()` so that it will wait for the DOM to load properly